# Postgres: Multiple conditions on jsonb object

Tags: sql, postgresql

This is the dataset with around 200,000 rows

```sql
"test"  "test"  "[{""field"": ""devops"", ""years"": 8}, {""field"": ""backend dev"", ""years"": 3}]"
"test"  "test"  "[{""field"": ""devops"", ""years"": 9}, {""field"": ""backend dev"", ""years"": 4}]"
"test"  "test"  "[{""field"": ""devops"", ""years"": 9}, {""field"": ""backend dev"", ""years"": 9}]"
```

I want to find all the users who's experience is :

- devops = +5years
- backend dev = +5 years

One condition is **working** in my query:

```sql
with parsed_exp as ( 
 select 
 "firstName", 
 "lastName", 
 experience, 
 jsonb_array_elements(experience) as e from users )
select * from parsed_exp 
where (e->>'field') = 'backend dev' and (e->>'years')::integer > 5
```

But two conditions together are not working:

```sql
with parsed_exp as ( 
 select 
 "firstName", 
 "lastName", 
 experience, 
 jsonb_array_elements(experience) as e from users )
select * from parsed_exp 
where 
(e->>'field') = 'backend dev' and (e->>'years')::integer > 5 and 
(e->>'field') = 'devops' and (e->>'years')::integer > 5
```

^^ **It's returning 0 rows**

Comment: That's invalid JSON to begin with. And what is `"test" "test"` in your sample data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on Postgres 12 or later, you can use a JSON path expression:

```
select *
from users 
where jsonb_path_exists(experience, '$[*] ? (@.field == "devops" && @.years > 5)')
  and jsonb_path_exists(experience, '$[*] ? (@.field == "backend dev" && @.years > 5)')
```

Comment: Is it possible with unnest as well. I was thinking a group by having on case when from unnest

Comment: When you unnest the elements you will have to aggregate them back in order to find those that fulfill both conditions

Comment: Absolutely would take an extra effort but would work either way your answer doest it perfectly. Is it also the case jsonb_path_exists there in every dbms? I would really appreciate if you could answer it using unnest not an OPs question but out of curiosity

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you please tell me why the query that I wrote is not working?